# Преобразовать char* в массив double [C++]

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Здравствуйте, задача состоит в следующем : 
Изначально нам дан **массив double**, который **нужно зашифровать xor-ом**, я **привожу массив double к char массиву** следующим образом:

```
    unsigned char *char_from_double = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&doubleArr);
```

После этого прохожу по нему xor-ом, и на этом этапе возник вопрос, **как его преобразовать обратно из char* в double массив?**
Просто привести char* к double массиву не получается

Как вариант, отдельно шифровать каждый элемент массива double, и хранить массив массивов char*, где один char* это одно double число, но подозреваю что это не очень хороший вариант

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точно так же только наоборот. `reinterpret_cast` преобразует только укзатель, сам массив остается неизменным. Если у вас алгоритм шифорвания корректный то должно работать так:

```
double data_1[DATA_SIZE] = {...};
unsigned char * byte_array_1 = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&data_1[0]);

auto secret = encrypt(byte_array_1, DATA_SIZE * sizeof(double));

double data_2[DATA_SIZE] = {...};
unsigned char * byte_array_2 = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&data_2[0]);

decrypt(secret, byte_array_2, DATA_SIZE * sizeof(double));

double * data_2_pointer = reinterpret_cast<double *>(byte_array_2);
```

Но обычно так не делают как вы описываете. Под зашифрованные данные нужно выделить отдельный массив байтов и в него складывать зашифрованные данные, а исходный массив изменять не надо. Так принято не только для шифрования, а вообще для всех видов подобных обработок данный например сжатия.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: "Под зашифрованные данные нужно выделить отдельный массив байтов и в него складывать зашифрованные данные, а исходный массив изменять не надо. Так принято не только для шифрования" - ложное утверждение. И самое главное, совершенно непонятно зачем так плясать?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов То есть принято портить исходные данные?

Comment: @Cerbo и даже более того: специально затирать их нулями!

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Ссылки, примеры?

Comment: Ну посмотрите на CryptEncrypt из WinAPI, например. Шифрует в тот же буфер, в котором plaintext содержится и иных вариантов не предполагает. Рекомендую еще в OpenSSL посмотреть про зануление всего, что только можно, подобного там хватает OPENSSL_cleanse(&c,sizeof(c)); /* security consideration */

Теперь ваша очередь давать ссылки на стандарты с "Под зашифрованные данные нужно выделить отдельный массив"

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов zlib например `ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT compress OF((Bytef *dest, uLongf *destLen, const Bytef *source, uLong sourceLen));`

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов в сжатии изображений принята схема с каллбеком, как-то так: `encode(void * raw, size_t raw_size, callback * call);` Вот нашел в  OpenSSL: `int RSA_public_encrypt(int flen, unsigned char *from, unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);` Самое главное что ни кто никогда не переписывает исходные данные. Это большое западло.

Comment: @Cerbo давайте не путать сжатие и шифрование?

Answer (score 4):

Никак его не надо преобразовывать к double, потому что создается только указатель на массив. Данные как до шифрования, так и после продолжают лежать в массиве doubleArr. Можете в отладчике посмотреть и убедиться.

Comment: Блин, точно, спасибо большое, я об этом совсем не подумал...